# How to assign to a data.table a variable name received as parameter in a function

Tags: r, function, variables, data.table

I need have a data.table named "clients", the name is same that is in my database. (this example is with table "clients" but i will need more tables with others names)

```
tbl_import <- function (table)
{
        sql<-glue_sql(paste0("select * from table"),.con=con)
    
    table <- dbGetQuery(con,sql)
    setDT(table)
      
    table <<- copy(table)
        table <<- table ##I replace with this too in another try but didn't work either
}
tbl_import("clients")
```

When i run this i don't have the data.table with the name of "clients",I get a table with name "table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `assign()` to create a variable with a custom name (`table_name`) in the caller environment (`parent.frame()`

```
tbl_import <- function (table_name) {
  sql <- glue_sql("select * from {`table_name`}",.con=con)
  x <- dbGetQuery(con,sql)
  assign(table_name, setDT(x), parent.frame())
}
tbl_import("clients")
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help! "assign" was the key

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the function to a new name.

```
clients <- tbl_import("clients")
```

Comment: It works but  Andrew response is more what i was looking for. with this solution i have to put twice the name of table and is just what i want to avoid. but thanks for response.